# Where do I ask about top contributors to a particular field?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I wanted to know about the top contributors to python programming language *(not limited to SO)*, and my web searching skills failed me. So I thought lets search on SO, and though initially I found it strange that I could not find any such question, it did not take me long to realize that my question is not about programming in a strict sense.

Now this is not only true to python, someone may wants to know top contributors to anything for example: Neural Networks or microprocessors.

Comment: As a question, this wont fly in any SE site that I know of. But is there a reason you can't use SO ranking tables? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers

Comment: Ok, my communication was not good enough. I meant top contributors to "python programming language" as a whole and not on stackoverflow only

Comment: That question is logically not on-topic on Stack Overflow, and I do not think it could be on-topic on another SE site. Check the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers).

Comment: ok, let me try to rephrase, when I say who are top contributors to neural network, list will go like - Geoffrey Hinton, Yoshia Bengio, Yann  Lecun and so on. Reading about these people gives me (and probably a lot of other people) a lot of inspiration. Similarly when we talk about python, we can see Guido, Travis Oliphant, Jake VanderPlas and so on. I wanted to know more about who created what, and their stories.

Comment: My last comment still applies.

Comment: But do you understand, your link to top contributors to SO is not what I was looking for, and I think probably I did a bad job at framing my original question. Probably most (or all) downvoters thought that I was looking for SO contributors.

Comment: I do understand. It would still be an off-topic question.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I know this is an off-topic question for SO, that I the precise reason I asked on meta that where we can ask such questions. By your response I get that is we can not.

Comment: As I said, I'm not aware of any site were such a question would be on topic. Not even close.

Comment: Chat is one place, or perhaps /r/python on reddit.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such information on Stack Overflow, or at least, not in the form of a Q&A. Like any other request for a *list of off-site resources*, requests for lists of contributors to a field or technology are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

> Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [...]

In practice, one may find that some social networks gather more people of some kind of technological stack than others. Here on SO, the best you can do is try and kindly ask if they know more at the respective chatroom.